# Selenium href click after inputting field

Tags: python, selenium, href

I am new to selenium and python and am hoping to get some guidance here.

I am trying to enter a zip code and then parse the resulting data that gets displayed.  The problem I have is that after entering a zip code I cannot seem to click on the correct href id.

site I am testing on is: https://www.citizensbank.com/custom/RegionializationGateway.aspx?targetpage=/loans/mortgage-refinance.aspx#

I am using selenium ver 3.141.0 and python 3.9.1

what I have tried is the following:
...

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('zip_input_region')
inputElement.send_keys(zip)

#Attempt 1 not working
searcher = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cta_btn")
searcher.click()

#Attempt 2 not working
element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_id("zip_submit_region")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_to_click)

#Attempt 3 not working
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Submit").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.url_changes(url))
```

...

What am I missing?  Appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following wait for the element to be clickable. Also added Options

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.citizensbank.com/custom/RegionializationGateway.aspx?targetpage=/loans/mortgage-refinance.aspx#')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "zip_input_region"))).send_keys(zip)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "zip_submit_region"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the same result with your code.  The zip code validates but the hyperlink is not executed.  It should take you to another page to show rate information.  I must be missing something else here.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Jon It seems to know it's a bot try the following change.